# Material Vertical stepper form is possible in Swift iOS Xcode

Tags: ios, swift, material-design, xcode9.2

I'm trying to implement the Material Vertical stepper form in swift

Unfortunately, I do not find any example implementations. Even Material Vertical stepper form does not implement this yet.

Anybody able to help with an example of the layout.

Answer (score 0):

You can use https://github.com/ton252/APProgressView#approgressview? Approgressview from objective c . It's horizontal stepper, but we can use by applied some customized and transforms.

Comment: Please write here the solution instead of including a link that could be broken in the future. Thanks!